# pyTorch gradient becomes none when dividing by scalar

Tags: python, pytorch

Consider the following code block:

```
import torch as torch

n=10
x = torch.ones(n, requires_grad=True)/n
y = torch.rand(n)
z = torch.sum(x*y)
z.backward()
print(x.grad) # results in None
print(y)
```

As written, `x.grad` is None. However, if I change the definition of `x` by removing the scalar multiplication (**`x = torch.ones(n, requires_grad=True)`**) then indeed I got a non-None gradient that is equivalent to y.

I've googled a bunch looking for this issue, and I think it reflects something fundamental in what I don't understand about how the computational graph in torch. I'd love some clarification. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you set `x` to a tensor divided by some scalar, `x` is no longer what is called a "leaf" `Tensor` in PyTorch. A leaf `Tensor` is a tensor at the beginning of the computation graph (which is a DAG graph with nodes representing objects such as tensors, and edges which represent a mathematical operation). More specifically, it is a tensor which was not created by some computational operation which is tracked by the `autograd` engine.

In your example - `torch.ones(n, requires_grad=True)` is a leaf tensor, but you can't access it directly in your code.
The reasoning behind not keeping the `grad` for non-leaf tensors is that typically, when you train a network, the weights and biases are leaf tensors and they are what we need the gradient for.

If you want to access the gradients of a non-leaf tensor, you should call the `retain_grad` function, which means in your code you should add:

```
x.retain_grad()
```

after the assignment to x.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

It is true that you need to maintain grad. However, the easiest correction to this issues it using torch.div() funciton.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please modify your answer by specifying how the user can solve it through some source code.